# How to open chrome developer console using Selenium in java?

Tags: selenium

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);     
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("i").perform();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you explain the use case for doing this?

Comment: @MrSolanki Can you update the question with your _usecase_ and the reason you want to open _chrome developer console_ while _Test Execution_ is in progress?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to perform the keyUp events for both the SHIFT and the CONTROL keys.

```
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("i").keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```